Convolution of sinusoid and running sum filter of order 5
Problem

Compute analytically the convolution between the impulse response of a running sum filter of order 5 and a sinusoid $\sin(20\pi t)$ sampled with $f_s = 50 \: \text{Hz}$.

Attempt
The impulse response of running sum filter is: $h[k]=\{1,1,1,1,1,1 \}$.
The sampled sine wave is: $f[k] = \sin(\frac{20}{50}\pi k) = \sin(\frac{2}{5}\pi k) \: \: k \in \mathbb{N}$.
The linear convolution formula is: $y[k] = \sum_{m=0}^k h[m]f[k-m]$, but because the filter impulse response has length 6 we can write
$$y[k] = \begin{cases}
\sum_{m=0}^k h[m]f[k-m] \: \: \: 0 \leq k \leq 4\\\\
\sum_{m=0}^5 h[m]f[k-m] \: \: \: k \geq 5
\end{cases} $$
The first sum is
$$\sum_{m=0}^k\sin\bigg(\frac{2}{5}\pi(k-m)\bigg) $$
The second sum is
$$\sum_{m=0}^5\sin\bigg(\frac{2}{5}\pi(k-m)\bigg) $$
I have trouble calculating these sums because they are sums of functions (of $k$) and not sums of numbers. How do I evaluate these sums?

Can you clarify if it's $k \in \mathbb{N}$ or $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Mine and the accepted answer assume the latter which may be wrong (and it's not what you wrote)

@Hilmar: Now that you mention it, both signals should be assumed to be causal in this problem, so $k \in \mathbb{N}$ should be used. However, we are supposed to calculate the respose using the convolution formula and not z-transform, and I doubt it is possible to arrive at a nice closed solution. But if you have any ideas I would be happy to see them.

Since the system is linear and time-invariant, we know that the output must be of the form
$$y[n]=A\sin(2\pi n/5+\phi)\tag{1}$$
where $A$ and $\phi$ are determined by the filter. These values could be computed in the frequency domain, but since the exercise requires to evaluate the convolution directly, let's try to arrive at $(1)$ by evaluating the convolution sum.
We can start from Eq. $(3)$ in Jdip's answer:
\begin{align*}
y[n] &= \sum_{k=n-5}^n\sin(2\pi k/5) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^5\sin(2\pi (k+n-5)/5) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^5\sin(2\pi (k+n)/5) \\
&= \textrm{Im}\left\{e^{j2\pi n/5}\sum_{k=0}^{5}e^{j2\pi k/5}\right\}\\
&= \textrm{Im}\left\{ e^{j2\pi n/5}\frac{1-e^{j2\pi\cdot 6/5}}{1-e^{j2\pi/5}}\right\}\\
&= \textrm{Im}\left\{ -e^{j2\pi n/5}\frac{\sin(6\pi/5)}{\sin(\pi/5)}\right\}\\
&= -\frac{\sin(6\pi/5)}{\sin(\pi/5)}\sin(2\pi n/5)\\
&= \sin(2\pi n/5)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
which has the desired form given by Eq. $(1)$. [Thanks to Hilmar for pointing out the last simplification.]

$-\frac{\sin(6\pi/5)}{\sin(\pi/5)} = 1$. The final solution can be written even simpler. It's just $\sin(2\pi n/5)$

@Hilmar: True, nice catch!

While we are at it, here is a "trick" answer. It's may not generally applicable but makes this case really easy. Since convolution is commutative we can write the running sum of order $M$ simply as the sum of  sine waves as
$$y_M[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{M} \sin[\frac{2\pi}{5}(n-k)] \tag{1}$$
Now we can make use of the fact that the sine wave has a period of 5. Every sum over 5 consecutively delayed sine waves will be the sum over an integer period which is zero. Every 5 consecutive contributors to the sum will cancel out. So we have
$$y_M[n] = y_{M+5m}[n] \forall m \in \mathbb{Z} = y_{\lfloor M/5 \rfloor}[n] \tag{2}$$
$y_M[n]$ is not only periodic in $n$ but it's also periodic in $M$ both with a period of 5.
That also means $y_5[n] = y_0[n] $ and hence we get
$$y_5[n] = y_0[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{0} \sin[\frac{2\pi}{5}(n-k)]  = \sin[\frac{2\pi}{5}n]\tag{3}$$
In other words: 5 of the 6 contributors cancel each other out and we are left with the original signal.
Transient response.
Since the original question postulates a one side sine wave, the steady state solutions is only correct for $ n \ge 5$. Assuming $x[n] = \sin(\frac{2\pi}{5} n) $ The answer including the transient response would be
$$y[n] = \begin{cases} 0 & n \leq 0 \\ x[1] & n = 1  \\ 
x[1]+x[2] & n = 2 \\ x[1] & n=3 \\ 0 &x = 4 
\\ x[n] & n \ge 5\end{cases}$$
which is obtained manually summing the first few elements and leveraging some symmetry properties of the sine wave.

I'm not sure whether just the steady state response was of interest (which, at the time of writing this, is what is provided by other answers) but if the full response (transient and steady state) is of any interest, I've provided it below. I've also generalised it to any frequency and any sum filter order so that the solution is more widely applicable (as I derive it, I will show explicitly where the specific question values should be substituted).
To solve it, I will use that time domain convolution is z domain multiplication, so transform to the z domain, do the algebraic manipulation, and transform back to the discrete time domain to obtain the final answer.
Firstly, note that given $k$ is a natural number, the sine wave is:
$$\sin\left[\omega_0 k\right]u[k]$$
Where $u$ is the Heaviside step function and $\omega_0=\omega T$, where $\omega$ is the sinusoid frequency (rad/s) and $T$ is the sample interval (s). In the question $\omega_0=\frac{2\pi}{5}$
The z transform of sine function is:
$$\frac{z^{-1}\sin[w_0]}{1-2\cos[w_0]z^{-1}+z^{-2}}=\frac{z^{-1}\sin[w_0]}{(1-e^{-i\omega_0}z^{-1})(1-e^{i\omega_0}z^{-1})}$$
The z transform of the running sum is:
$$1+z^{-1}+z^{-2}+z^{-3}+z^{-4}+...+z^{-n}=\sum_{m=0}^nz^{-m}=\frac{1-z^{-n-1}}{1-z^{-1}}$$
Where $n$ is the filter order (in the question $n=5$). Note that putting the running sum in this final form keeps the number of terms in the final discrete time expression constant regardless of filter order (which keeps things simpler when the filter order is large).
Multiply the two prior expressions in consideration of the z transform convolution property, then do a partial fraction expansion to facilitate putting the final z domain expression in a form that can easily be found in tables of z transform pairs:
$$\frac{(1-z^{-n-1})z^{-1}\sin[w_0]}{(1-z^{-1})(1-e^{-i\omega_0}z^{-1})(1-e^{i\omega_0}z^{-1})}=(1-z^{-n-1})z^{-1}{\sin[w_0]}\left(\frac{A}{1-z^{-1}}+\frac{B}{1-e^{-i\omega_0}z^{-1}}+\frac{C}{1-e^{i\omega_0}z^{-1}}\right)$$
Where:
$$A=\frac{1}{2-2\cos[\omega_0]}$$
$$B=\frac{1}{(1-e^{i\omega_0})(1-e^{i2\omega_0})}$$
$$C=\frac{1}{(1-e^{-i\omega_0})(1-e^{-i2\omega_0})}$$
Thus, the final z domain expression in a form that can easily be transformed to the discrete time domain by referring to tables of z transform pairs is:
$$(1-z^{-n-1})\left(\frac{\sin[w_0]}{2-2\cos[\omega_0]}\frac{z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}}-\frac{\cos[1.5\omega_0]-\cos[0.5\omega_0]z^{-1}}{2\sin[0.5\omega_0]}\frac{z^{-1}}{1-2\cos[\omega_0]z^{-1}+z^{-2}}\right)$$
Giving the final discrete time solution to be:
$$\frac{\sin[w_0]\left(u[k-1]-u[k-n-2]\right)}{2-2\cos[\omega_0]}-\frac{\cos[1.5\omega_0]}{2\sin[0.5\omega_0]\sin[\omega_0]}(\sin[\omega_0k]u[k]-{\sin[\omega_0(k-n-1)]}u[k-n-1])+{\frac{\cos[0.5\omega_0]}{2\sin[0.5\omega_0]\sin[\omega_0]}(\sin[\omega_0(k-1)]u[k-1]-\sin[\omega_0(k-n-2)]u[k-n-2])}$$
Here is some code in Matlab comparing the numerical solution with the full solution and just the steady state solution:
w = 20*pi;      % sinusoidal frequency
T = 1/50;       % sample rate
n = 5;          % running sum filter order

w0 = w*T;       % normalised frequency

% create signal
N = 20;
k = (0:N-1)';
x = sin(w0*k).*(k>=0);

% compute terms in full response solution
a = sin(w0)*((k-1>=0) - (k-n-2>=0))/(2-2*cos(w0));
b = -cos(1.5*w0)/(2*sin(0.5*w0)*sin(w0))*(sin(w0*k).*(k>=0) - sin(w0*(k-n-1)).*(k-n-1>=0));
c = cos(0.5*w0)/(2*sin(0.5*w0)*sin(w0))*(sin(w0*(k-1)).*(k-1>=0)-sin(w0*(k-n-2)).*(k-n-2>=0));

% compute steady state solution found in other answers
steady_state = sin(2*pi*k/5);

% compare
subplot(1,2,1); plot(k*T, [filter(ones(1,n+1),1,x), a+b+c, steady_state],'.-')
title('response'); legend({'numerical','full solution','steady state only'}); xlabel('time (s)')
subplot(1,2,2); plot(k*T, filter(ones(1,n+1),1,x) - [a+b+c, steady_state],'.-')
title('residuals'); xlabel('time (s)')
legend({'full solution','steady state only'})

This produces the following plots:


You're close but this should be simpler:
Linear convolution:
$$y[n] = (f * h)[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f[k]h[n-k]\tag{1}$$
Because of the definition of $h$, we know that $h[n-k] = 1$ for $0 \leq n-k \leq 5$ so $(1)$ becomes:
$$y[n] = \sum_{k=n-5}^{n}f[k]\tag{2}$$
So substituting $f[k]$:
$$y[n] = \sum_{k=n-5}^{n}\sin(0.4\pi k)\tag{3}$$
